# Can Eclipse IDE plug-ins extend other plug-ins

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to make a simple syntax highlighting plug-in for one of Perl's many HTML templating systems.  I'd like to just extend the WST HTML/XML editor and add a few rules and such to it instead of poorly reinventing the wheel.  Is this possible and advisable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to extend an eclipse plugin

Yes. They are called [Extension Points](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html). However, the plugin being extended is what defines the extension points for pluggable functionality. You could also just simply make the WST plugin a dependency of your plugin.